# How to specify printing type?

Tags: c#

Developing a WPF application, i've created a custom PrintDialog for several reasons.
In this PrintDialog, i've some options that users can modify often, and a button to allow users to access the printer properties and modify it if they want to.

To do that, we simply call the native function :

```
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "DocumentPropertiesW", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern int DocumentProperties(
      IntPtr hwnd,
      IntPtr hPrinter,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pDeviceName,
      IntPtr pDevModeOutput,
      IntPtr pDevModeInput,
      int fMode);


    /// <summary>
    /// Affiche la fenêtre de propriété de l'imprimante de la queue fournie
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printQueue"></param>
    private void OpenPrinterDialog(PrintQueue printQueue)
    {

        PrintTicketConverter ptc = new PrintTicketConverter(printQueue.FullName, printQueue.ClientPrintSchemaVersion);
        IntPtr mainWindowPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

        byte[] myDevMode = ptc.ConvertPrintTicketToDevMode(printQueue.UserPrintTicket, BaseDevModeType.UserDefault);
        GCHandle pinnedDevMode = GCHandle.Alloc(myDevMode, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr pDevMode = pinnedDevMode.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        int res = DocumentProperties(mainWindowPtr, IntPtr.Zero, printQueue.FullName, pDevMode, pDevMode, 14);
        if (res == 1)
            printQueue.UserPrintTicket = ptc.ConvertDevModeToPrintTicket(myDevMode);

        pinnedDevMode.Free();
    }
```

In development computers, it works fine. But on the testing computers, the printing type ramdomly change. [Picture](http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=140425015611997650.gif).
On testing computers, it goes sometimes to normal printing, sometimes to secure printing, sometimes on something else, with no reason. On the same computer, opening the window, cancel and open again can show 2 differents results.

The only difference we've seen for now is that on development we've .Net 4.5 installed, and on testing they only have 4.0. We're planning to install 4.5 on one of those machine to see if this "solve" the problem, but it can't be a solution for us.

So, does anyone see a reason for this, or maybe know a way to specify that we want a "normal print" ?

Thx for you time.

Comment: You are using p/invoke, the fw version has nothing to do about it. Also, that property is driver-specific, you should ask to the printer's manufacturer

Comment: I also don't see how fw can have an action on this, except if there is some changes to PrintTickets.
About driver-specific, i could do that if this problem was on every application, but it's only on our application, so i guess we're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the "normal" way without any dll imports and the dafault gui for configuring your printer?

I use a FlowDocument which I generate in my programmcode then i use a flowdocument viewer to show the document and set default printersettings.

Code for print:

_document is a FlowDocument with my Contents for the Print.

```
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
            printDlg.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
            printDlg.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;
            printDlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = _ticket.PageOrientation;
            printDlg.PrintTicket.PagesPerSheet = _ticket.PagesPerSheet;
            Nullable<Boolean> print = printDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (print == true)
            {
                _document.PageWidth = printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth;
                _document.ColumnWidth = _document.PageWidth;

               ... do some format stuff
                IDocumentPaginatorSource idocument = _document as IDocumentPaginatorSource;


                printDlg.PrintDocument(idocument.DocumentPaginator, _document.Name);




            }
```

Comment: We can't use the default GUI mainly because we've some custom settings, and we don't want to show 2 windows to the user.

Comment: Hmm I would not use the DLL import and use the second window ;), cant you prepare your print and show a preview? there you could add a print button and show the "normal" print dialog with your printticket where you set your parameter?.